# run a role twice in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I wrote my playbook this way:

```yaml
- name: install kubernetes 
  hosts:  [kuber]
  roles:
    - A
    - B
    - C
    - B
```

which means I wanted to run `B role` twice, but based on result, the second `B` hasn't even run.

What should I do to run a role multiple times?

Answer (score 3):

Ref: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-duplication-and-execution

> To make roles run more than once, there are two options:
>
> 1. Pass different parameters in each role definition.
> 2. Add `allow_duplicates: true` to the `meta/main.yml` file for the role.

So an easy workaround in your case could be as follow:

```yaml
- name: install kubernetes
  hosts:  [kuber]
  roles:
   - role: A
   - role: B
     vars:
       fake_param: firstinclude
   - role: C
   - role: B
     vars:
       fake_param: secondinclude
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `include_role`:

```yaml
- name: install kubernetes 
  hosts:  [kuber]
  tasks:
    - include_role:
      name: A
    - include_role:
      name: B
    - include_role:
      name: C
    - include_role:
      name: B
```

Comment: yep, this is one way. but still I don't understand why second B role didn't execute !!

Comment: Because it is a list, which got normalized.

Comment: @jack: not exactly. If you `allow_duplicates: true` in role's `meta/main.yml`, and keep the list as is, the role will be played twice.

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks.